# Retrieving Value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello having a bit of problem retrieving a value so i might use it.
This is is where i should get my value.

```php
<input type="text" class="typed" readonly="readonly" name="levele"
    value="<?php
    if($get_display->level== "Grade 2") {
        echo "Grade 4"; $lbl="Grade 4";
    }?>">
```

For a simple test i will use the value Grade 4 because i know what the outcome I'm suppose to have. This is the code that i want to retrieve the value of "levele" so it may perform a SQL statement. For example i have 5 sections that are for grade 4 so i was thinking on using this sql statement.

```php
<select name="section_id">
    <option>SECTIONS</option>
    <?php 
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_section where level='".$_GET['levele']."'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<option value='.$row['section_id'].'>' .$row['section_name']. '</option>';
        }
    ?>  
</select>
```

So far i am unable to retrieve "levele" so it may be used it the sql, also tried $_POST and $_request but nothing and i check if levele does have the value Grade 4 and it does also in my database. Would appreciate any help on this. Because after i have retrieve the 5 sections I will try to automatically select one section where for example if the student has a grade of 90 the section should be "A" I'm going to do it with if else. so i would appreciate any help to solve these problems.

Comment: This is horribly exploitable. Please read this: [SQL Injection Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: You might try: echo mysql_error(), "<br />";

Comment: Right after mysql_query(), for debugging.

Comment: @Mythril Thanks, This is just a simple Project but i will mostly use mysql_real_escape_string() after I'm done with everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three main problems here that I think you should address:

Firstly, in your code at the top:

```
<input type="text" class="typed" readonly="readonly" name="levele" value="<?php if( 
     $get_display->level== "Grade 2"){ echo "Grade 4"; $lbl="Grade 4";}?>">
```

Your code will only echo and set a value if `$get_display->level` is equal to 2. Did you mean to add in an else statement as well in case the value is something other than `Grade 2` perhaps?

```
<?php 
    if($get_display->level== "Grade 2")
    { 
        echo "Grade 2"; $lbl="Grade 2";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Grade 4"; $lbl="Grade 4";
    }
?>
<input type="text" class="typed" readonly="readonly" name="levele" value="<?php echo $lbl; ?>">
```

Secondly, your form section of code seems to be missing quotes around the values:

```
echo '<option value='.$row['section_id'].'>' .$row['section_name']. '</option>';
```

I think you meant to use this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['section_id'].'">' .$row['section_name']. '</option>';
```

Lastly, your code is very vulnerable to injection attacks. You *really* should look at moving to [PDO](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://au.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) when dealing with form data.

Edit: This is just an afterthought, but I can't see anywhere that you set `$result` to a valid connection, but I assume that this is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I have read some articles regarding SQL injections and I would like to perform prepared statements but its in mysqli and i have a few days to pass this so i wont be able to shift from mysql to mysqli so I will just settle for mysql_real_escape_string().. Yes i have connection

Comment: @Tony All good, just pointing out that it is something you should address. Any improvement in security is a good one - and going back and improving something after it is launched/delivered is the sign of a good developer who actually cares :)

Comment: Yeah I was trying to go with bcrypt but i just played safe with sha+salt . . .btw i will do a multi if else . . . because i have many values just using one right now to test if its working.

Comment: @Tony You could also look into a `switch()` statement (pretty much same same) but can be easier to read and more intuitive in the case of a `default` case if no other conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="typed" readonly="readonly" name="levele" value="<?php if( 
 $get_display->level== "Grade 2"){ echo "Grade 4"; **$lbl="Grade 4";**}?>">

remove ** portion and run ....

<select name="section_id">
<option>SECTIONS</option>
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_section where level='".$_GET['levele']."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<option value='.$row['section_id'].'>' .$row['section`enter code here`_name']. '</option>';
    }
?>  
</select>
```